# app.config will not budge in console application System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, .net-4.5, app-config

I have searched stack and google for this problem and couldnt seem to find any leads

Problem:
C# .net 4 console application
Makes calls to webservice 
Webservice is: https and asmx

Here is the crunch i have the app working perfectly fine in .net 4.5 but since server it runs on is windows 2003 so i have to downgrade to .net 4 and this is where the problem is

Without modifying much of the working code i removed ServiceRefernce1 for .net 4.5 and added ServiceRefernce2 for .net 4 and now app.config will not work and keep giving

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException
```

my app.config for .net 4.5 (working one)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="RSAWebServiceApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>

  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!--
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="VCSampleServiceSoap" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
  -->
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="defaultBasicHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://this.testservice.com/Sample/VCSampleService.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultBasicHttpBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.VCSampleServiceSoap" name="VCSampleServiceSoap"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

now after much clean up .net 4 app.config (non working)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="IPSOSHarness2.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="VCSampleServiceSoap" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://this.testservice.com/Sample/VCSampleService.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="VCSampleServiceSoap"
                contract="ServiceReference1.VCSampleServiceSoap" name="VCSampleServiceSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

i have tried

```
<system.ServiceModel>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior"
      name="VCSampleServiceSoap">
        <endpoint address="https://this.testservice.com/Sample/VCSampleService.asmx"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="defaultBasicHttpBinding"
                    contract="ServiceReference1.VCSampleServiceSoap" 
                    name="VCSampleServiceSoap" />

      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="defaultBasicHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

</system.ServiceModel>
```

either way i couldnt make it work in .net 4, so any help either on fixing this or just compiling .net 4.5 working code so it works without .net 4.5 framework on windows server 2003? it needs to be console app and i know there are ways to make it work in asp.net but i cant change from console.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to resolve this by doing following:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="defaultBasicHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://this.testservice.com/Sample/VCSampleService.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultBasicHttpBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.VCSampleServiceSoap" name="VCSampleServiceSoap"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```